# How to define a type alias for a template in a class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, using, type-alias

For example

```
struct Option_1
{
    template<class T> using Vector = std::vector<T>;
};
```

I can do

```
typename Option_1::Vector<int> v;
```

But I prefer the following

```
Vector<Option_1, int> v;
```

or similars without the word "typename". I define an alias

```
template<class Option, class T> using Vector= typename Option::Vector<T>;
```

but failed with unrecognizable template declaration/definition. How to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the keyword [template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name#The_template_disambiguator_for_dependent_names) for the dependent template name `Option::Vector`, i.e.

```
template<class Option, class T> using Vector = typename Option::template Vector<T>;
//                                                              ~~~~~~~~
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/ZMTSTU57061)